# MOSFET circuit operating point

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, homework

Yesterday I spent about two hours trying to calculate the operating point of this circuit without success but I can't accept my defeat.

[image]

The exercise asks to:

1. "Complete" the operating point and calculate the value of \$R_1\$.
   (I don't know what "complete" means, at first I though that some of the parameters of the MOSFETs were already given but they aren't)
2. Calculate the value of \$ K_{M3}\$ when \$ I_{D3} = 1.5mA\$.

\$M_1\$ is a PMOS while \$M_2\$ and \$M_3\$ are NMOS.

The given parameters are: \$V_{DD} = 20V\$, \$V_T = 1V\$, \$K_{M1} = 25\mu A/V^2\$, \$K_{M2} = 15\mu A/V^2\$, \$R_2 = 800K\Omega\$, \$R_3 = 240K\Omega\$, \$R_S = 17.5K\Omega\$, \$R_K = 4.8K\Omega\$, \$R_A = 2K\Omega\$.

Usually, for the analysis of MOSFET circuits I start by supposing that they work in saturation region, I derive the parameters \$V_{GS}\$ (or \$V_{SG}\$), \$V_{DS}\$ (or \$V_{SD})\$ and \$I_{D}\$ with network analysis and then verify the hypothesis (I don't work with software).

Out of desperation I wrote down every \$KVL\$ and \$KCL\$ and the only thing I could come up with was calculating the value of \$I_A\$ using \$ I_{D3} = 1.5mA\$ (which I don't think it was legal to do) so that I could work with the \$KCL)\; \frac{V_{DD}}{R_1+R_2}+I_{D1}+I_A=0\$ and the \$KVL)\; \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_{DD}+V_{SG1}+R_SI_{D1}=V_{DD}\$ but the calculations became so messy that I couldn't go on.

Can anyone see a clean modus operandi?

Comment: @greybeard I never deleted and re-posted a post.

Comment: Hint: \$I_{D3}\$ will be largely independent of Vo. \$Ia = I_{D3} + I_{Rk}\$

Comment: @greybeard I don't understand how that helps me. If I use \$I_{D3} = 1.5mA\$, I already have \$V_O\$ and therefore \$V_{DS3}\$. My biggest problem is \$R_1\$.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, I can say that \$I_{D2} = \frac{K_{M2}}{K_{M3}}I_{D3}\$, but if I don't have \$K_{M3}\$ I can't have \$I_{D2}\$.

Comment: @greybeard I also thought that my professor forgot to give us some other parameter.

Comment: Yep, like \$K_{M2} = K_{M3}\$ - so underspec'ed for 1.&2. . (BTW: tag [tag:circuit-analysis])

Comment: Notice since Rs is large in value (17.5kΩ) the Id1 current needs to be much lower than Id3. To force M1 and M2 to work in saturation.  For example, you could pick Id = 150µA. And now you should be able to solve for K_M3 and R1. Also what equation you are  using for Id current in saturation?  Id = K*(Vgs - Vt)^2 or this one Id = K/2 * (Vgs - Vt)^2 ?

Comment: @G36 That's great insight, thanks! I use the first one, since I consider \$K =\frac{1}{2} \mu_n C_{OX}\frac{W}{L}\$.